# Datatype mismatch in criteria expression , when querying excel file using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a scenario in which I have to query an excel sheet using SQL.
In excel I have a column called "test_case_id", which holds alphanumeric value
I use the following vbscript code to get the values from excel.
The "test_case_id" column in excel has been formatted as "General".
When the value for this column is an integer ( ex: 1,2,3... )

```
SELECT  *   FROM [05 Invest Allocate$] WHERE [test_case_id] =1
```

The above query seems to work

But when the "test_case_id" column has a character in it ( ex: 5b, 6b,7b)

```
SELECT  *   FROM [05 Invest Allocate$] WHERE [test_case_id] ='5b'
```

the above query gives an error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Could some one please help me resolve this in such a way that i can query either as a string or as an integer in the where clause ?

Full code is :

```
strQuery = "SELECT  *   FROM [05 Invest Allocate$] WHERE [test_case_id] ='5b'"
j_drive_root_path="C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\"

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
            strUserName =objNetwork.UserName

            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set original = fso.GetFile(j_drive_root_path & "temp_invest_allocate.xls")

            strCopyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\" & strUsername & "\copyofexceltable.xls"
            original.Copy (strCopyPath)

            'Set the connection object and path to the copied spreadsheet       
            Set objAdCon =  CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & strCopyPath & ";" & _
                      "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""

            'Open spreadsheet
            objAdCon.Open strConn

            'Create a recordest object (to store the results of the query)
            Set record_set = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

            'Run the query
            record_set.CursorLocation = 3

            record_set.Open strQuery, objAdCon, 1, 3

            If Not record_set.EOF Then
                Set client_to_accountID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                client_to_accountID.CompareMode=vbTextCompare
                client_to_accountID.RemoveAll

                Do Until record_set.EOF
                        tmp_val=Trim(Cstr(record_set("id").Value))
                        print "id=" & tmp_val
                        record_set.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If ' End of if not record_set.EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819 it states:

> For example: In your eight (8) scanned rows, if the column contains
>   five (5) numeric values and three (3) text values, the provider
>   returns five (5) numbers and three (3) null values. In your eight (8)
>   scanned rows, if the column contains three (3) numeric values and five
>   (5) text values, the provider returns three (3) null values and five
>   (5) text values. In your eight (8) scanned rows, if the column
>   contains four (4) numeric values and four (4) text values, the
>   provider returns four (4) numbers and four (4) null values. As a
>   result, if your column contains mixed values, your only recourse is to
>   store numeric values in that column as text, and to convert them back
>   to numbers when needed in the client application by using the Visual
>   Basic VAL function or an equivalent.
>
> To work around this problem for read-only data, enable Import Mode by
>   using the setting "IMEX=1" in the Extended Properties section of the
>   connection string. This enforces the ImportMixedTypes=Text registry
>   setting. However, note that updates may give unexpected results in
>   this mode. For additional information about this setting, click the
>   article number below to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge
>   Base: 194124  PRB: Excel Values Returned as NULL Using DAO
>   OpenRecordset

You may need to change TypeGuessRows to 0 in the registry at

```
Hkey_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Jet/4.0/Engines/Excel/
```

Comment: Thanks Remou. I had tried by changing the format of the column in Excel to text before. But it didnt work. But as a work around , after changing the format of the column , I had to retype the values for the column for that to take effect !!

Comment: I have previously tested with SQL Server Express and Excel. IMEX=1 and a change to the registry worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Win7 64bit the location is My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel